# How to remove .txt or .docx at end of string in python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to create a list of all file names from a specific directory. My code is below:

```
import os
#dir = input('Enter the directory: ')
dir = 'C:/Users/brian/Documents/Moeller'
r = os.listdir(dir)
for fnam in os.listdir(dir):
    print(fnam.split())
    sep = fnam.split()
```

My output is:

```
['50', 'OP', '856101P02.txt']
['856101P02', 'OP', '040.txt']
['856101P02', 'OP', '50.txt']
['OP', '040', '856101P02.txt']
```

How would I be able to remove anything to the right of a "." in a string, while keeping the text to the left of the period?

Comment: Watch out, you can have periods in your filename, so you don't want to just split and keep whatever is to the left of the first period but the last period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.path.splitext` to split a filename to two parts,
keeping only the extension in the right, and everything else on the left.
For example,
a path like `some/path/file.tar.gz` will be split to `some/path/file.tar` and `.gz`:

```
base, ext = os.path.splitext('path/to/hello.tar.gz')
```

If you want to get rid of the `.` in the `ext` part,
simply use `ext[1:]`.

If the file has no extension, for example `path/to/file`,
then the `ext` part will be the empty string.
This is a nice feature,
so that `os.path.splitext` always returns a tuple of two elements,
and this way the `base, ext = ...` example above always works.

> I am trying to create a list of all file names from a specific directory. 
>   [...]
>   How would I be able to remove anything to the right of a "." in a string, while keeping the text to the left of the period?

To get the base names (filenames without the extension) of a specific directory `somedir`, you could use this list comprehension:

```
basenames = [os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir(somedir)]
```

Comment: My answer is for arbitrary strings, for filenames, you should definitely use this method.

Comment: This looks great, however how would I remove the for each file in my path? Right now in my example, the end of the path is Moeller, which is a folder and does not have any .txt or .docx at the end, but the files in that folder do, is there a way to do this without have to enter each file's specific path to do so? Thanks!

Comment: @Bkal05 I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. I added some more info to my answer to try to address your main question. If you still need more info, please clarify.

Comment: @janos, that edit did it for me, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Basically, what you do is start splitting from the right with `rsplit` and  then instruct it to split only once.

`print "a.b.c.d".rsplit('.',1)[0]`

prints `a.b.c`

Comment: That's an interesting solution too.

Answer (score 0):

From there, find the period and take everything up to that position.  In simple steps ...

```
for fnam in os.listdir(dir):
    nam_split = fnam.split()   # "sep" is usually the separator character
    print(nam_split)
    ext_split = nam_split.rsplit('.', 1)  # Split at only one dot, from the right
    file_no_ext = ext_split[0]    # The first part of the split is the file name
    print(file_no_ext)
```